# How to get the text between two words in R?

Tags: r, string

I am trying to get the text between two words in a sentence.
  For example the sentence is -

```
x <-  "This is my first sentence"
```

Now I want the text between `This` and `first` which is `is my` . 
I have tried various functions from R like `grep`, `grepl`, `pmatch` , `str_split`. However, I could not get exactly what I want .

This is the closest what I have reached with `gsub`.

```
gsub(".*This\\s*|first*", "", x)
```

The output it gives is

```
 [1] "is my  sentence"
```

In reality, what I need is only

```
[1] "is my"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `.*` at the end to match zero or more characters after the 'first'

```
 gsub('^.*This\\s*|\\s*first.*$', '', x)
 #[1] "is my"
```

Answer (score 14):

Another approach using [`rm_between`](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/rm_between.html) from the **qdapRegex** package.

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, 'This', 'first', extract=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "is my"
```

Answer (score 9):

Since this question is used as a reference, I'll add some possible solutions to build a complete overview. Both are based on a `look-ahead/look-behind` regex pattern.

**base R**

```
regmatches( x, gregexpr("(?<=This ).*(?= first)", x, perl = TRUE ) )
```

**stringr**

```
stringr::str_extract_all( x, "(?<=This ).+(?= first)" )
```