# Search two words in close proximity to each other in R, return close sentences in table

Tags: r

I am trying to find the sentences (3 sentence before, and 3 sentences after), if and only if, **word1** and **word2** are in close proximity with each other. If the words are not close to **30 words spaces**, between each other, then no results found. If they are **30 word spaces** apart, then return 3 sentences before and 3 sentences after.

I have managed to:

- find first word occurence
- second word occurence
- sentence split ([R code to search a word in a paragraph and copy preceding as well after sentences from key words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989074/r-code-to-search-a-word-in-a-paragraph-and-copy-preceding-as-well-after-sentence))

However, I am unsure how to achieve this without tokenising into words.
I have found these useful, but not what I am looking for

- [How to calculate proximity of words to a specific term in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057639/how-to-calculate-proximity-of-words-to-a-specific-term-in-a-document)
- [How to get the text between two words in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530930/how-to-get-the-text-between-two-words-in-r)
- [How to calculate proximity of words to a specific term in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057639/how-to-calculate-proximity-of-words-to-a-specific-term-in-a-document)

Any help would be appreciate. A tibble dataframe of 2 articles used in example below.

Thank you

```
 #Dataframe

date<-c("2018-01-03","2018-06-10 ")

text=c(c("Bumblebees are found mainly in northern temperate regions, thought 
here are a few native South American species and New Zealand has some 
naturalised species that were introduced around 100 years ago to pollinate 
red clover. They range much further north than honey bees, and colonies can 
be found on Ellesmere Island in northern Canada, only 880 km from the north  
pole!)",c("With the recent popularity of using bumblebees in glasshouse 
pollination they will probably be found in most parts of the world before, 
especially Bombus terrestris which seems to be the most popular species sold 
for this purpose. Recently there have been proposals to introduce bumblebees 
into Australia to pollinate crops in glasshouses. Now, though I dearly love 
bumblebees, I do think that this might not be a very good idea. No matter 
what security measures are taken, mated queens WILL escape eventually and 
that will probably lead to their establishment in the wild. And yet another 
non-native invasion of a country that has suffered more than most from such 
things. This invasion may or may not be benign, but isn't it better to err 
on the side of caution? Apparently there are already colonies of Bombus 
terrestris on Tasmania, so I suppose it is now only a matter of time before 
they reach the mainland.")))


library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tblcombo<-tibble(date,text)
View(tblcombo)

word1<-c("invasion")

#First Word occurence
one_word <- function(text, word_1){
text1 <- tblcombo %>%
  mutate(comp_det = str_detect(tolower(text), tolower(word_1))) %>%
  filter(comp_det == TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(first_word_Word = rep(word_1, length(comp_det))) %>%
  dplyr::select(date,text,first_word,comp_det)
return(text1)
}

firstword<-one_word(tblcombo,word1)
View(firstword)

#Second word occurence
word2<-c("colonies")

second_word <- function(one_word,word2){
 word_second<-one_word%>%
  mutate(cat_det = str_detect(tolower(text), tolower(word2))) %>%
  filter(cat_det == TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(second_word = rep(word2, length(cat_det))) %>%
  dplyr::select(date,text,first_word,comp_det,second_word)
return(word_second)
}

secword<-second_word(firstword,word2)
View(secword)

 #Extract 3 sentences before and 3 sentence word occurs
extract_sentences_3_either_side_word <- function(text, word){
  rem <- c("Mr. ", "Wm. ", "St. ", "Co. ", "Sc. ", "Dr. ", "Ms. ", "No. ", "Us. ", "By. ", "Cs. ", "a.m.")
  rem <- paste("(",paste(rem, collapse = "|"),")",sep="")
  text <- str_replace_all(text, rem, "")

  split_text <- unlist(str_split(text, "\\. "))

  inds <- which(str_detect(tolower(split_text), tolower(word)))

  p33 <- function(ind, split_text){
    if ((ind-3) < 1) {
      ind <- 4
    }
    pst33 <- paste(na.omit(split_text[(ind-3):(ind+3)]), collapse = ". ")
  }
  s33 <- paste(map_chr(inds, ~p33(.x, split_text)), collapse = "     - NEXT -     ")
  return(s33)
}

extract_sentences_3_either_side_word(tblcombo$text,word1)

#Distance between words
distance <- function(string, term1, term2) {
words<-tolower(string)
words<-gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',string)
words <- strsplit(words, "\\s")[[1]]
indices <- 1:length(words)
names(indices) <- words
abs(indices[term1] - indices[term2])
}

#Applying to table secword
data<-secword%>%mutate(dist_words=lapply(text,distance,first_word,second_word)<50)
```

Comment: [tidytext](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext) would make this tokenization much, much easier.

Comment: Hi @alistaire - thank you for the suggestion. Please can you show how to use tidytext. Thank you

Comment: Something like `text_df %>% 
    unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = 'sentences', to_lower = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(sentence_id = row_number()) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, sentence, drop = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(word_id = row_number(),
           good_word = word %in% c('invasion', 'colonies'))`, though I'm not sure where you want to go after that

Comment: Hi @alistaire thank you for the direction. My goal is to identify 3 sentences before and 3 sentences after, if both words are close to each other (30 word spaces). The code you provided, only provide the instances these words occur, but not the sentences if the close proximity is true. Trust you can provide more help. Thank you

Comment: By "word spaces" do you mean the number of spaces between words? If so, the tokenized data will let you calculate that. If you mean characters, that's possible, as well.

Comment: @alistaire - I mean spaces between words. I tried to use the distance function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316823/getting-distance-between-two-words-in-r, but was not successful. Any guidance would be helpful

Comment: Hi all - code now includes distance function, which I am applying to table secword. I obtain following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. Please help