# Extracting text between two different characters in R Dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe from IMDB that shows titles like this in a dataframe:

```
tt0031381   movie   Gone with the Wind  Gone with the Wind  0   1939    \N  238 Drama
tt0116695   movie   Jerry Maguire   Jerry Maguire   0   1996    \N  139 Comedy
```

I'm trying to extract the data between `movie` and `0`

I tried to look in stack overflow for an answer but many of them were for specific characters and it was difficult for me to distinguish the ones in the problem and apply it to my text issue.

dataframe info:

```
movies <- data.frame(V1=c("tt0031381    movie   Gone with the Wind  Gone with the Wind  0   1939    \N  238 Drama", "tt0116695  movie   Jerry Maguire   Jerry Maguire   0   1996    \N  139 Comedy")
```

I did try this

```
movies$title <- sub('movie', '0', movies$V1)
```

but it only repeated the column. Can someone assist?

I've seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530930/how-to-get-the-text-between-two-words-in-r) but I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

I also tried this:

```
library(qdapRegex)

movies$title <- rm_between(movies$V1, 'movie', '0', extract=TRUE)[[1]]
```

but that just applied the first title to every row, which wasn't accurate

Comment: Could you add your data as a `dput`?

Comment: I wanted to create a new column in my dataframe. This "tt0116695   movie   Jerry Maguire   Jerry Maguire   0   1996    \N  139 Comedy" came from movies$V1 if that's what you're asking

Comment: @sotos I don't know how to apply that answer to my situation, which is why i asked this.

Comment: What they're asking is that you edit the question to include the output from `dput(movies)`. Or if that is too large `dput(head(movies))`. That will generate reproducible data that people can use to answer.

Comment: I think the second answer is very easy to implement. As for the first, simply change the words you want to extract the string between. Overall, both answers are very clear. If you are having problems, you might have a different structure, in which case, I recommend you update with a reproducible example

Comment: I added dataframe information just now. thank you for your input

Comment: I am trying to get a new column added to a dataframe and the situation that marked this question as a dupe applies to a string, not a dataframe.

Comment: For me this works, `gsub('^.*movie\\s*|\\s*0.*$', '', movies$V1)`